# Python's equivelant for php's getLoginUrl for Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I have some experience working with facebook's php sdk. Now I need to use python to create a facebook app, but the python sdk is not as complete as the one for php

Is there a port of the php sdk to python?

One of the methods missing is the below

```
 $session = $facebook->getSession();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
            'canvas'    => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history'
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

As for as the python transformation (provided you use the app engine) is concerned , you have an already defined python script in the examples/OAuth directory of your python-sdk . Hack it up to add the value:pair scope='email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history' , (here scope does the job of req_perms) . Also supply your APP ID and App Secret in the global variables specified at the beginning. And receive the corresponding access_token. Now this access_token will have the specified authorization rights